# Как рассчитать оценки для каждой группы и вывести средний балл по каждой группе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ЧТО НУЖНО ПОЛУЧИТЬ?**

Как видно на прикреплённом рисунке. Есть группа и список студентов с оценками.Нужно ,чтобы под группой было их общее количество среднего баллов.
То есть внизу списка под каждой группой Средний балл = 12,4(например)

**ЧТО У МЕНЯ ЕСТЬ НА ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ?**

Есть функция состоящая из двух частей:

```
def srtgr(self):
              """Номер группы в порядке убывания по успеваемости"""
              countfour1=0
              countfive1=0
              counttri=0
              for student in studinfos:
                     if student.markgeometry==4:
                          countfour1+=1
                     if student.markalgebra==4:
                          countfour1+=1
                     if student.markinformatika==4:
                          countfour1+=1
                     if student.markgeometry==5:
                          countfive1+=1
                     if student.markalgebra==5:
                          countfive1+=1
                     if student.markinformatika==5:
                          countfive1+=1
                     if student.markgeometry==3:
                          counttri+=1
                     if student.markalgebra==3:
                          counttri+=1
                     if student.markinformatika==3:
                          counttri+=1
              sredball=((countfive1+countfour1+counttri)/3)
              print("Средний бал = ", sredball)
```

Рабочий код подсчитывания оценок всех студентов(НЕ ПО ГРУППАМ)

Прошу не критиковать обильное количество `if` просто этот, мягко говоря, странный вариант, рабочий и считает количество оценок.
Дальше идёт вывод студентов по группе(то что видно на рисунке)

```
gl=dict()
      sredballs=[]
      for s in studinfos:
           sd=gl.pop(s.numbgroup,dict())
           sd[s.surn]=[s.markgeometry,s.markalgebra,s.markinformatika]
           gl[s.numbgroup]=sd
      for k,v, in gl.items():                  
                s=f'Group: {k}: \n'
                for stdn,grds in v.items():                  
                     s+=f'  {stdn}\t{grds[0]},{grds[1]},{grds[2]} \n'
                print(s)
```

**В ЧЁМ ПРОБЛЕМА?**

Если я сделаю так:
То есть в цикл и в словарь начну добавлять формулу расчёта среднего балла,то будет ошибка что в словаре должно быть 2,а не 3 значения,не говоря уже о внутренних ошибках.
Как можно добавить формулу расчёт среднего балла и уже потом вывести её через словарь.
Т.е `(Группа,средний балл) =>(Group,sredball)`.
Например `(ВМО11,12.5)`

Я решил создать отдельный словарь где будет группа и количество средних баллов.

Но я не могу понять,куда мне добавить в цикл добавления словаря, подсчёт оценок и формулу среднего балла.
Примерный нерабочий набросок кода:

```
for s1 in studinfos:
               sd1=srdbl.pop(s1.numbgroup,dict())
               sd1[s1.numbgroup]=[s1.sredball]
               srdbl[s1.numbgroup]=sd1
          for namegroups,itms, in srdbl.items():                  
                    s1=f'Group: {namegroups}: \n'
                    for group,sredbals in itms.items():                  
                         s1+=f'  {group}\t{sredbals[0]} \n'
                    print(s1)
```

Comment: добавьте пример входных данных. именно как он выглядит в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Я тут начеркал кое что, вот главный файл

```
from funck import fucnks

massGroup = [
    dict(Иванов=[3, 4, 5], Петров=[5, 5, 5], Дубовская=[4, 4, 5]),
    dict(Пеньков=[4, 5, 3], Деревко=[2, 5, 4], Осинова=[4, 3, 5]),
    dict(Кузнецов=[4, 3, 2], Молотков=[3, 5, 3], Берёзин=[5, 5, 5], Клёнова=[3, 4, 5])
]


def averageCalculation(group):
    keys = fucnks.getKeys(group)  # получаем ключи из словаря

    massForAssessment = []  # массив куда сохраняются оценки всех учеников

    while True:
        lenMass = len(keys)  # получение длинны массива, для перебора
        for i in range(lenMass):
            name = str(keys[i])  # получаем ключ
            getName = group[name]  # достаём значение по ключу
            lenMassForAssessment = len(getName)
            for i in range(lenMassForAssessment):
                massForAssessment.append(int(getName[i]))  # добавляем в массив оценку
        break
    summa = fucnks.addingElementsInAnArray(massForAssessment)  # получаем сумму оценок
    mid = str(summa / len(massForAssessment))  # получаем среднее значение
    print(mid[0:4])  # выводим


def main():
    for i in range(len(massGroup)):
        print(massGroup[i])
        averageCalculation(massGroup[i])


main()
```

тут файл функций

```
class fucnks:
    def addingElementsInAnArray(array):
        lengArray = len(array)
        summa = 0
        for i in range(lengArray):
            summa += array[i]
        return summa

    def getKeys(group):
        return [i for i in group]
```

вот вывод:

```
 {'Иванов': [3, 4, 5], 'Петров': [5, 5, 5], 'Дубовская': [4, 4, 5]}

> 4.44

 {'Пеньков': [4, 5, 3], 'Деревко': [2, 5, 4], 'Осинова': [4, 3, 5]}

> 3.88 

{'Кузнецов': [4, 3, 2], 'Молотков': [3, 5, 3], 'Берёзин': [5, 5, 5], 'Клёнова': [3, 4, 5]}

> 3.91
```

Задание я не совсем чётко понял, если есть замечание пишите в комментарии я перепишу код

Comment: Честно говоря слишком круто для меня.как для начинающего.

В главном сообщении есть скрин.
Так вот как мне сделать так,чтобы под всеми фамилиями и оценками,выводился средний бал всей группы(Например идёт группа ВМО11,далее список студентов и под фамилиями средний балл всей группы)?

Формулы подсчёта среднего балла и формула нахождения оценок у меня есть уже.

Comment: Вас попросили выше привести "пример входных данных. именно как он выглядит в коде". Вы сознательно это не делаете? Если приведете -  может вам и дадут пример кода, а так - кто его знает, как у вас данные организованы и как их разумно обрабатывать.